# Is there a more efficient way to write $('parent > child')?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

Given the following selector $('parent > child'), I believe jQuery will first query for all 'child' elements before filtering down to those that are direct descendants of 'parent'. This can be very inefficient.

My first instinct is to use $('parent').find('child'), but the result is obviously not the same as $('parent > child').

Is there a better way to write this selector?

Comment: "*I believe jQuery will first query for all 'child' elements before filtering down to those that are direct descendants of 'parent'.*" - I would love to know if jQuery does that...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I got it from here a couple months ago: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method that only selects the immediate children.

Also, don't worry about this stuff! Unless you have a gigantic app or it's out of curiosity there's no reason to delve into this. If you are using a selector way too often just "cache" it: `$tabs = $('.tabs')`. A good practice is to use $ in front of variables that represent selectors.

Comment: I didn't realize the children() method only got the immediate children. Yeah, this is mostly out of curiosity. I always cache my selectors, but this particular question has been nagging me for a while. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe jQuery will first query for all 'child' elements before filtering down to those that are direct descendants of 'parent'.

Actually, this assumption isn't *quite* correct:

Whenever possible, jQuery uses the browser's native `querySelectorAll` DOM traversal, which is as fast as it gets.

So, as long as:

- you don't do [jQuery specific selector stuff like `:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/),
- you can safely assume a [non-primeval browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility),

… you should be just fine with using `parent > child` without having to care about performance.

If you happen to need any of the jQuery specific selectors, keep this in mind:

> Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method.
>
> To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":first").

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response. Check out the first paragraph in the following link, which is what I'm basing my assumption on: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

`$('parent > child')` will retrieve all first occurring instances of a child.  If you have a div with divs within divs, `$('div#one > div')` will only return the 2nd level divs, instead of all  of the children. I don't see anything wrong with this as far as efficiency goes. However, Radagaisus's suggestion works as well.

```
<div id="one">
  <div> <!-- returned -->
    <div></div> <!-- ignored -->
    <div></div> <!-- ignored -->
    <div></div> <!-- ignored --> 
  </div>
  <div> <!-- returned -->
    <div></div> <!-- ignored -->
    <div></div> <!-- ignored -->
    <div></div> <!-- ignored --> 
  </div>
</div>
```